# What do 'Delimiter' and 'InheritsFromParent' attributes mean in .vsprops files?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005

I can't seem to find any *useful* documentation from Microsoft about how one would use the `Delimiter` and `InheritsFromParent` attributes in the `UserMacro` element when defining user Macros in `.vsprops` property sheet files for Visual Studio.

Here's sample usage:

```
<UserMacro Name="INCLUDEPATH" Value="$(VCROOT)\Inc"
    InheritsFromParent="TRUE" Delimiter=";"/>
```

From the above example, I'm guessing that *"inherit"* really means *"a) if definition is non-empty then append delimiter, and b) append new definition"* where as the non-inherit behavior would be to simply replace any current macro definition.  Does anyone know for sure?  Even better, does anyone have any suggested source of alternative documentation for Visual Studio `.vsprops` files and macros?

NOTE: this is *not* the same as the `InheritedPropertySheets` attribute of the `VisualStudioPropertySheet` element, for example:

```
<VisualStudioPropertySheet ... InheritedPropertySheets=".\my.vsprops">
```

In this case *"inherit"* basically means *"include"*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*[Answering my own question]*

`InheritsFromParent` means prepend.  To verify this, I did an experiment that reveals how User Macros work in Visual Studio 2008. Here's the setup:

- Project `p.vcproj` includes the property sheet file `d.vsprops` ('d' for *derived*) using the `InheritedPropertySheets` tag.
- `d.vsprops` includes the property sheet file `b.vsprops` ('b' for *base*.)
- `p.vcproj` also defines a Pre-Build Event which dumps the environment.
- Both `.vsprops` files contain User Macro definitions.

**b.vsprops**

```
...
<UserMacro Name="NOENV" Value="B"/>
<UserMacro Name="OVERRIDE" Value="B" PerformEnvironmentSet="true"/>
<UserMacro Name="PREPEND" Value="B" PerformEnvironmentSet="true"/>
...
```

**d.vsprops**

```
...
<VisualStudioPropertySheet ... InheritedPropertySheets=".\b.vsprops">
<UserMacro Name="ENV" Value="$(NOENV)" PerformEnvironmentSet="true"/>
<UserMacro Name="OVERRIDE" Value="D" PerformEnvironmentSet="true"/>
<UserMacro Name="PREPEND" Value="D" InheritsFromParent="true"
    Delimiter="+" PerformEnvironmentSet="true"/>
...
```

**p.vcproj**

```
...
<Configuration ... InheritedPropertySheets=".\d.vsprops">
<Tool Name="VCPreBuildEventTool" CommandLine="set | sort"/>
...
```

**build output**

```
...
ENV=B
OVERRIDE=D
PREPEND=D+B
...
```

From these results we can conclude the following:

1. `PerformEnvironmentSet="true"` is necessary for User Macros to be defined in the environment used for build events.  Proof: `NOENV` not shown in build output.
2. User Macros are ***always*** inherited from included property sheets regardless of `PerformEnvironmentSet` or `InheritsFromParent`.  Proof: in `b.vsprops`, `NOENV` is not set in the environment and in `d.vsprops` it is used without need of `InheritsFromParent`.
3. Simple redefinition of a User Macro ***overrides*** any previous definition.  Proof: `OVERRIDE` is set to `D` although it was earlier defined as `B`.
4. Redefinition of a User Macro with `InheritsFromParent="true"` ***prepends*** the new definition to any previous definition, separated by a specified `Delimiter`.  Proof: `PREPEND` is set to `D+B` (not `D` or `B+D`.)

Here are some  additional resources I found for explanation of Visual Studio `.vsprops` files and related topics, it's from a few years back but it is still helpful:

[understanding the VC project system part I: files and tools](http://blogs.msdn.com/josh_/archive/2004/02/03/66965.aspx)

[understanding the VC project system part II: configurations and the project property pages dialog](http://blogs.msdn.com/josh_/archive/2004/02/04/67705.aspx)

[understanding the VC project system part III: macros, environment variables and sharing](http://blogs.msdn.com/josh_/archive/2004/02/05/68366.aspx)

[understanding the VC project system part IV: properties and property inheritance](http://blogs.msdn.com/josh_/archive/2004/02/09/70335.aspx)

[understanding the VC project system part V: building, tools and dependencies](http://blogs.msdn.com/josh_/archive/2004/02/13/72844.aspx)

[understanding the VC project system part VI: custom build steps and build events](http://blogs.msdn.com/josh_/archive/2004/03/02/83035.aspx)

[understanding the VC project system part VII: "makefile" projects and (re-)using environments](http://blogs.msdn.com/josh_/archive/2004/05/18/134638.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There's documentation on the UI version of this [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a2zdt10t.aspx).
A lot of the XML files seem somewhat undocumented, often just giving a [schema file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ak4435es.aspx).  Your guess as to how they function is pretty much right.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the whole story.

- Delimiters are not inherited. Only
  the list of items they delimit are inherited: The same user macros can have different delimiters in different property sheets but only the last encountered delimiter is used. (I write "last encountered" because at project level, we cannot specify a delimiter and what gets used there is the last property sheet that specified inheritance for that macro)
- Delimiters works only if made of a
  single character. A delimiter longer
  than one character may have its
  first and/or last character stripped
  in some cases, in a mistaken attempt
  to "join" the list of values.
- $(Inherit) appears to work inside
  user macros. Like for aggregate
  properties, it works as a placeholder for
  the parent's values, and it can appear multiple times. When no $(Inherit) is found, it is implied at the beginning if the inheritance flag is set.
- $(NoInherit) also appears to work in user's macros(makes VC behaves as if the checkbox was unticked).
- User macros (and some built-ins) appears
  to work when used for constructing a property sheet's path (VC's own project converter uses that feature). The value
  taken by user's macros in this situation is not
  always intuitive, though, especially if it gets redefined in other included property sheets.
- In general, what gets "inherited" or concatenated are formulae and not values (ie. you cannot use a user macro to take a snapshot the local value of (say) $(IntDir) in a property sheet and hope to "bubble up" that value through inheritance, because what gets inherited is actually the formula "$(IntDir)", whose value will eventually be resolved at the project/config/file level).
- A property sheet already loaded is ignored (seem to avoid that the same property sheet has its user macros aggregated twice)
- Both "/" and "\" appear to work in
  property sheet paths (and in most
  places where VS expects a path).
- A property sheet path starting with
  "/" (after macros have been resolved) is assumed to be in "./", where '.' is the location of the
  calling sheet/project). Same if the path does not start with "./", "../" or "drive:/" (dunno about UNC).