# How to configure visual studio 2008 to select the correct .lib based on configuration?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

The distribution of [assimp](http://assimp.sourceforge.net/) comes with a lib folder. This folder has the following sub folders :

```
assimp_debug-dll_win32
assimp_debug-dll_x64
assimp_release-dll_win32
assimp_release-dll_x64
```

Each of those folders has a single file, assimp.lib. How can I include the correct lib based on my configuration (debug/release)? Currently, assimp is in a folder outside of my project and I've added the paths to Tools->Options->VC++ Directories->Library files, but I'm not sure its working.

Comment: If you go to project properties, each configuration(debug/release...) has it's own set of settings. You can go to linker options for individual configurations and set additional lib dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the library directories to the project itself rather than as a global setting in visual studio.

To do this, you can right click on the project in the solution explorer.  Then under the VC++ directories section, add in the correct path to assimp.  You should just add the path that corresponds to the current (i.e. debug or release/win32 or x64) setup to this list.  There should be a drop down at the top to select the current configuration that you are editing.

This applies to VS2010 anyway, I'm not 100% sure about VS2008.  The library path may be under Project Settings -> Linker ->General -> Additional Library Directories  if the VC++ directories section does not exist.

Comment: If I add the paths to the project settings, it becomes difficult to share the project. I guess I should copy the libs and header inside my project folder in that case, right?

Comment: That's one way of dealing with it.  You could also copy all your external libraries to a seperate location, and then use an environment variable or a property contained in a .vsprops file to specify the location in your project settings.  Then any other users will just need to edit the .vsprops file/set the environment variable to their location for the external libraries.

Comment: For the .vsprops options, you may want to have a read of this on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a4xbdz1e%28v=VS.90%29.aspx  or some of the links & answers from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284265/how-to-use-vsprops-file-to-override-vc-directories-in-ms-visual-studio

Comment: I thought about this too. Is one or the other considered best practice or more appropriate under certain contexts?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm best placed to answer that to be honest, may be an idea to post another question.  I have a feeling using a property sheet would be considered best practice generally, as it doesn't clutter your PC up with excess environment variables, anyone who gets your code will automatically have some defaults, and it's potentially a lot more flexible.  But I've seen environment variables used for this purpose a lot as well, so I guess it's up to you to decide which suits your needs best.

Answer (score 1):

You should be branching the include paths for each build configuration using properties -> linker -> additional include directories. this will solve your problem.

a secondary option is to use `#pragma comment(lib,"<lib name>")` and use the path to the library you want to link to, then using `#if/#endif` you can branch based on the current build version.

you can test it using dependency walker, process explorer or any debugger.

Comment: This method will only work fine if the first path that has been added to the VC++ settings is the path to the correct .lib file surely?  As the .libs all have the same file name, will VC++ not just pick the first one it comes to, regardless of whether it's the correct one?  Or do I underestimate it's inteligence

Comment: @obmarg: I misread his post, though he edited the *per build* settings, changed it to reflect what I though he did...

Answer (score 1):

You could do it using preprocessor directives:

```
#ifdef __DEBUG
#pragma comment(lib,"c:/Path/assimp_debug-dll_win32/assimp.lib")
#else
#pragma comment(lib,"c:/Path/assimp_release-dll_win32/assimp.lib")
#endif
```

Comment: This should solve the problem of debug and release build (I didn't test). I also notice some libraries can select their lib files according to whether the c++ runtime library is static linked. Do you know how they achieved this? Or what macro may be defined in that case?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't, but a quick google took me to [this mskb article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/140584), I'm not sure if that would help at all. Also back to the main questions the _WIN64 and _WIN32 macros could be used to select the right lib for x86/x64 builds in VS2008.